# How to send multiple messages over a TCPStream in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a list of string messages which I want to send over to another machine by opening a TCP connection between the both of them. I'm not looking to use existing solutions like mpsc::channel.

I had seen examples about how we can do the same thing in tokio by using intervals and poll writes. But assuming we want to send the messages as fast as possible how do we do that? I also tried using tokio::spawn and loop through the entire queue to write the required messages but always ended up getting errors from the socket ( cannot be moved....)

```
let done = listener
    .incoming()
    .for_each(move |socket| {
        let server_queue = _cqueue.clone();
        let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();
        let sender = Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1))
            .for_each(move |_| {
                writer
                    .poll_write(server_queue.pull().borrow())
                    .map_err(|_| {
                        tokio::timer::Error::shutdown();
                    })
                    .unwrap();
                return Ok(());
            })
            .map_err(|e| println!("{}", e));
        ;
        tokio::spawn(sender);
        return Ok(());
    })
    .map_err(|e| println!("Future_error {}", e));

tokio::run(done);
```

Using this I was able to get messages on the consumer side but I feel like intervals slow us down because we wait before sending other messages. Is there another way to achieve something similar without using interval?

Comment: What prevents you from just writing this as a loop? Nothing in this requires `futures` as you're using `poll_write()` as opposed to (properly) using something on top

Comment: To be more specific, `pull()` isn't returning a future, `poll_write()` isn't returning a future either, so *what do you need the entire future chain for*?

Comment: you mean use something like ```while server_queue.get_size() > 0 { socket.write_all(server_queue.pull()) } ``` ?

Comment: For instance, or just `write()`. You do not need the timing iterator in your case as every single one of your calls is blocking. That's what I don't get

Comment: Do note that in general **blocking calls** like yours are a bad idea, for obvious reasons, so that's where I would focus my efforts if I were you, not on the "speed"